# How can I automatically adjust unit expression (mm, cm, m, km) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, unit-conversion

I'm graphing a large number of plots whose data vary substantially. The values are in scientific notation ranging from E-9 to E+3 for a particular unit and I need to adjust that in the axis label as well as in the data.

For example, if I have a data range that's on the order of E-6, is there a module or function that can automatically change the data and the units from 0.000001 m (meters) to 1.0 um (micrometers)?

Note: all of the data is in the form X.XXXXXXE+X, if that matters, but I can turn it into floats if necessary.

Comment: Try pint: https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.2/

Comment: You can define a function that calculates and plots the numbers that correspond to the desired unit; just specify the unit as an input in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why a special package or function would be required to change from meters to micrometers. This is a simple multiplication by `1e6`.

If your data in meters is `data_meters`, you get the data in micrometers `data_mu` by

```
data_mu = data_meters * 1.e6
```